# Detecting if a point is inside a rectangle

Tags: intersection

I have mouse coordinates in 2D game (x and y) and a rectangle (x, y, width, height).
How do I determine if the point is in the rectangle? I do not have any code to post here. I'm just searching for help.

Comment: What approaches have you tried?  Did you draw out a picture of what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While Zhen's example code is perfectly fine, I'd use one big expression (might not be possible based on your actual language):

```
bool pointInRectangle(Rectangle rect, Point point) {
    return p.x >= r.x && // point is right of the left edge
           p.y >= r.y && // point is below the top edge
           p.x <= r.x + r.w && // point is left of the right edge
           p.y <= r.y + r.h; // point is above the bottom edge
}
```

Of course, the whole orientation depends on your coordinate system (e.g. is positive y downwards or upwards). Also using `>=` and `<=` over `>` and `<` determines whether the edges of the rectangle are considered to belong to the actual rectangle.

Comment: in the last row p.y <= r.y + r.y don't you have a mistake?

Comment: Argh, almost same problem as Zhen. :) Now it's fixed

Comment: sorry, I made the mistake, you the c&p :), but yours is more complete

Comment: If your language supports shortcircuits of boolean operations use this version, if not use 4 IFs to enable early out. It might be only 4 comparisons, but still: It is 4 comparisons. (Plus two additions.)

Answer (score 2):

Pseudocode:

```
function check( r, p )
    if( p.x < r.x or p.x >= (r.x + r.width) ) then return false
    if( p.y < r.y or p.y >= (r.y + r.height) ) then return false

    else return true
```

Comment: r.width or r.height int the second if statement?

Comment: Correct, that's a typo in the code example.

Comment: @mario, thx, copy and paste blame :D